# CPACK .deb installer backup previous installed version

Tags: cmake, deb, cpack

Is there a way to backup the previous installed version of a .deb package generated by cpack? 
I have a project that i need to deploy manually on multiple equipments in a live production site. To minimize error and time spent deploying, i would like to use cpack and a .deb generator to create a package. 
But i also want to keep the previous installed version, and config files for fast roll-back.

I have already have a package with can be successfully installed with it's configuration files. Contained in a folder with the version as a name. But when I install the new version it automatically removes the older version. Is there a way to stop the installer from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by moving away from the .deb package and I'm instead using the .stgz package with a custom script. 
To create this script have a cmake folder in your project for cmake scripts. This is done by setting following line into your cmake file.

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources/CMake")
```

Copy a CPack.STGZ_Header.sh.in file into this directory. Normally you will find one in /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/.
Edit this file at will to reflect it what you want to do. Make sure to leave the 3 line that really unpack your package untouched.